# Javascript and PHP Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, php

I have small code that generated javascript error when I want to display in console $my_var:
I want to display $my_var in the console (I will use it later for append it to a div with jQuery) but I get : `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

PHP:

```
$my_var = '<script id=\'et4pages\'></script>';
echo '<a href="javascript:display_content(\''. $my_var .'\');">click here</a>';
```

Javascript :

```
function display_content(link) {
            console.log(link);
    }
```

Comment: What error is showing ?

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: just display the $my_var, I will use it later for jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this , let me know how much it works then tell me what you want in that OR try it by yourself

```
    <?php 
$my_var = "<script id=\'et4pages\'></script>";
echo '<a href="javascript:display_content(\''. $my_var .'\');">click here</a>';
?>
<script>
function display_content(link) {
            console.log(link);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but the problem was not in "click here", I just replaced a language var by simply "clic here " for that example

Comment: i have made some changes now it showing in console please check

Comment: You should explain what did you change.

Comment: i have replaced the ' to " in $my_var